# TtlExpired status while trying to ping the server

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, ping

I am using below code to check whether server is available or not

```
bool isReachable = false;

        Ping pinger = new Ping();
        try
        {
            PingOptions opt = new PingOptions(255, false);
            PingReply reply = pinger.Send("www.stackoverflow.com", 1000, new byte[32], opt);

            isReachable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
        }
        catch (PingException)
        {
            // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
        }
```

I am not getting Success status from server instead I am getting as **System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.TtlExpired**.

I tried different hosts like www.google.com, www.wikipedia.org, but not getting success status from server. I am able to ping without any problem in command prompt

I tried without ttl option, but same response only.

```
PingReply reply = pinger.Send("www.stackoverflow.com");
isReachable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
```

Comment: Well yes, `http://www.google.com` isn't an IP name or address - it's a URL. You would use `www.google.com` as just the name to look up the address for,.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks, I changed, but still I am getting same error.

Comment: You appear to still have a `/` at the end. That's not part of the address either .

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thank you...

Comment: it says in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hzczzed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can increase the ttl. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Default, I tried Max ttl value, but not working, updated my question

Comment: google.com uses very short ttl values to allow it to update servers often. You should use another server to test it with. Also, update your answer to remove the slash, it is confusing at the moment.

Comment: @Lukos, I am getting same status for all servers, what could be the reason?

Comment: TTL is used to ensure that echo requests do not carry on forever if they cannot find their destination. The number decreases by 1 on each hop and when it reaches zero, it dies. Is it possible that you have to set this number on Ping before using it?

Answer (score 0):

```
            PingReply reply = pinger.Send("www.google.com/");
```

should be

```
            PingReply reply = pinger.Send("www.google.com");
```